# How can i simplify this query about reservation?

Tags: php, mysql

I have hotel reservation system, when the user enters a new reservation date with the period I need to retrieve all the unreserved rooms,

reservations table contain room_id, startdate, period

I wrote this query, just need to simplify it

```
select * 
from rooms 
where id in (
   select room_id 
   from reservations 
   where '2018-6-11' not BETWEEN date_at and date_add(date_at, INTERVAL period day) 
   and '2018-6-30' not between date_at and date_add(date_at, INTERVAL period day) 
   and date_at not between '2018-6-11' and '2018-6-30' 
   and date_add(date_at ,INTERVAL period day ) not between '2018-6-11' and '2018-6-30' ) 
or id not in (select room_id from reservations)
```

Comment: I'd be tempted to store reservation end date instead but of period

Comment: Also, see about JOINs, and the test for overlaps is much simpler than this. Event A overlaps Event B if Event A starts before Event B finishes and ends after Event B starts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about converting `IN` clause into equivalent joins? See below query if it works in your case:

```
SELECT *
FROM rooms rm
JOIN 
   (SELECT room_id rmid
  FROM reservations
  WHERE '2018-6-11' NOT BETWEEN date_at AND date_add(date_at, INTERVAL period DAY)
  AND '2018-6-30' NOT BETWEEN date_at AND date_add(date_at, INTERVAL period DAY)
  AND date_at NOT BETWEEN '2018-6-11' AND '2018-6-30'
  AND date_add(date_at ,INTERVAL period DAY ) NOT BETWEEN '2018-6-11' AND '2018-6-30'
  ) tb1  
ON  rm.ID = tb.rmid 
JOIN reservations rv
ON rm.ID <> rv.room_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's break this down into 2 sub problems.

- Get all rooms which are never booked.
- Get all rooms which never clash with booked rooms' timings.

In the query, I have assumed `$start_date` and `$end_date` are the PHP variables which have user selected values stored in them.

```
(select * 
from rooms where room_id NOT IN (select room_id from reservations))

UNION

(select *
from rooms where room_id IN (
   select room_id 
   from reservations 
   where $start_date not BETWEEN date_at and date_add(date_at, INTERVAL period day) 
   and $end_date not between date_at and date_add(date_at, INTERVAL period day)
   and ($start_date > date_add(date_at, INTERVAL period day) OR $end_date < date_at)
))
```

Comment: The question was how to `simplify it` - I wouldn't recommend a UNION select as a simplification because it makes queries harder to debug.

Comment: Ok, fair enough. But can you let me know how it is `hard` to `debug`?

Comment: `UNION` may lead to performance issues. Read this https://www.percona.com/blog/2007/10/05/union-vs-union-all-performance/

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do 2 `IN` queries. 
Since in your first `IN` query you have only `NOT` clauses, you can change those to `NOT IN` and remove the `NOT`s in the subquery.
That will also remove the second `OR IN`.

```
select * 
from rooms 
where id not in (
   select room_id 
   from reservations 
   where '2018-6-11' BETWEEN date_at and date_add(date_at, INTERVAL period day) 
   or '2018-6-30' between date_at and date_add(date_at, INTERVAL period day)
   or date_at between '2018-6-11' and '2018-6-30' 
   or date_add(date_at ,INTERVAL period day ) between '2018-6-11' and '2018-6-30' ))
```

Basically this query translates to:
Give me all rooms for which there is no reservation where my start- or end-date lies in between the reservation time.

*EDIT*:

Thanks to @vivek_23 I realized the query cannot be simplified in terms of the inner where conditions - nonetheless this version reduces the amount of queries to the database to 2.

Comment: @MatthiasS Let's consider a room has been booked between `2018-6-12` and `2018-6-18`. Here, neither `2018-6-11` is between those 2 dates and neither is `2018-6-30`. But there is a clash.

Comment: @XING Why will I comment something like that unncessarily? I don't see why it should be ignored.

Comment: @vivek_23 you are right, I thought that I thought it through but I didn't. So the extra checks are necessary :-) I will edit my answer. The "Ignore.." comment was because XING posted another comment before but deleted it. I think it supposes to mean I should ignore the earlier comment - would make sense to delete it though :)